# Proving one expressions is greater than the other using limits?

Tags: real-analysis

In general, is it sufficient to show that one of them increases faster than the other?

$$1-P_{k,1}< or > (1-P_{k,2})(M+B(1-p))/(M+B))$$

where $P_{k,1}$  and $P_{k,2}$  are decreasing with M.
$P_{k,1}=P_{k,2}$ iff $B=0$. 
$$P_{k,1}, P_{k,2}\ge 0$$
$$P_{k,1}, P_{k,2},p\le 1$$

Comment: Unclear, please add details. Random example: $x/(x+1)$ increases faster than $1$ (positive $x$), but is always smaller.

Comment: To check if a function is greater than the other, you have to compare their values at a starting point, then compare their rate of change, e.g., if $f_1(x = x_0) = 1$ and $f_2(x = x_0) = 2$ and if $f_1$ decreases faster than $f_2$, then $f_1 < f_2$, for $x >= x_0$.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.